# Converting .docx to pdf with libreoffice using php

Tags: php, pdf, docx, libreoffice

I am trying to convert .docx file to .pdf using libreoffice.

my libreoffice installed directory is

```
C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 4
```

using commandline  i am getting output with

```
C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 4\program>soffice.exe -headless -convert-to pdf c:\temp\test.docx -outdir C:\temp
```

but in php no output with

```
$command = '"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 4\program\soffice.exe" -headless -convert-to pdf c:\temp\test.docx -outdir C:\temp';
exec($command, $output);
```

how to solve this ? thanks inadvance.

Comment: Try doing this before the $command statement, `cd C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 4\program\soffice.exe`.

Answer (score -2):

For more documentation click [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.1/en-US/text/shared/guide/start_parameters.html)

```
    function convert_any_file_to_pdf($file) {
        $file_path =  $file->getRealPath();
        $outputPdfPath = storage_path('app/public/pdf_save_dir_name_here');

        $output=null;
        $retval=null;

            // LibreOffice command to convert DOCX to PDF
            $command = "libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir {$outputPdfPath} {$file_path}";

            $status = exec($command,$output,$retval);

            if($retval === 0){    
                return ['message' => 'success'];
            }
            else{
                return ['message' => 'failed'];
            }
    }

    convert_any_file_to_pdf('example.docx'); // callback function
```